# Sin permisos para ingresar administrador drupal

Tags: drupal

Tengo una pagina hecha en Drupal los descargué y lo hice local pero al momento de ingresar al administrador me sale este mensaje:

> You are not authorized to access this page.

Utilice esta ruta `http://localhost/advil/?q=admin`.
Saben como habilitar el permiso ¿para ingresar el administrador?, probé en esta url localhost/advil/?q=user ingresa pero es para usuarios y no se puede administrar la pagina muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de drupal estás usando?

Comment: @blonfu Drupal 7.5

Comment: No entiendo muy bien. Drupal crea un usuario administrador cuando lo instalas, sólo tienes que loguearte con ese usuario.

Comment: @blonfu no es que sale ese acceso no autorizado al momento de hacer login como administrador osea no deja ni ingresar los datos para iniciar sesion.

Comment: Que raro. ¿Y si pones está url: http://localhost/advil/?q=user?

Comment: @blonfu no ese es la ruta como para entrar como usuario y no como administrador.

Comment: Es la página de login. Puedes entrar con cualquier usuario desde ahi

Comment: ¿son correctos los permisos para los archivos y carpetas(chmod) y cambiaste el propietario(chown)?

Comment: @ReneLimon  si si tiene persmisos, puedes decirme como se cambia el propietario(chown?. Con el usuario no de ja administrar la pagina.

Comment: eso depende mucho del sistema operativo que estés utilizando.

Comment: @ReneLimon Estoy usando windows 8.1 de 64 bits

Comment: [aqui](http://superuser.com/q/106181) hay una respuesta para cambiar el propietario. Por otro lado [aquí](https://www.drupal.org/node/2399055) hay posibles razones por las cuales podía suceder esto, al parecer tiene que ver con la caché.

Comment: ¿Que significa "con el usuario no puedes administrar la pagina"? ¿Con que usuario te logueas? Tienes que entrar como administrador,

Comment: @blonfu Si al ingresar no sale nada para administrar pero es cuando uno ingresa a localhost/advil/?q=user.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes drush puedes intentar este comando:

```
drush uli
```

Esto generará un one-time-login link.

Saludos